# How to access child menu items in Backpack for Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-backpack

I installed the MenuCRUD from the Backpack Add-On list:
https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/MenuCRUD#usage-in-your-template

and I put the example code into my blade, but it only shows the first level menu items, *as expected*.

This is the code I use:

```
@foreach (\Backpack\MenuCRUD\app\Models\MenuItem::getTree() as $item)
  <a class="text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-500" href="{{$item->url()}}">{{ $item->name }}</a>
@endforeach
```

now the documentation states that I should use `$item->children` to access the children of the menu items. I tried it with the following code:

```
@foreach (\Backpack\MenuCRUD\app\Models\MenuItem::getTree() as $item)
      <a class="text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-500" href="{{$item->url()}}">{{ $item->children->name }}</a>
@endforeach
```

but it gives me this error `Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.`
But I can see `[NAME]` inside the array list.

```
      [ORIGINAL:PROTECTED] => ARRAY
                    (
                        [ID] => 6
                        [NAME] => Testing-Name
                        [TYPE] => INTERNAL_LINK
                        [LINK] => /TEST/LINK1
                        [PAGE_ID] => 
                        [PARENT_ID] => 2
                        [LFT] => 
                        [RGT] => 
                        [DEPTH] => 
                        [CREATED_AT] => 2021-11-06 10:20:20
                        [UPDATED_AT] => 2021-11-06 10:20:20
                        [DELETED_AT] => 
                    )
```

I called the debugging above over:

```
@foreach (\Backpack\MenuCRUD\app\Models\MenuItem::getTree() as $item)
   {{print_r($item->children)}}
@endforeach
```

how can I call the children?

Comment: $item->children is a collection of items, it doesn't have a url property

Comment: @OMR yes, that makes sense, I update the code. I pasted it in falsely. I meant  `$item->children->name`

Comment: yes, it's the same, $item->children is a collection, it doesn't have a 'name' property, if you want the names of the children you should loop over them.

Comment: So I would use `(\Backpack\MenuCRUD\app\Models\MenuItem::getTree() as $item->children)` instead of the current one? Because I tried it to loop it that way but it shows "Attempt to assign property "children" on null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you take a look at the https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/MenuCRUD/blob/b4a64a454985f8203efa166a2d5dfebc304d2a48/src/app/Models/MenuItem.php#L34

the method you call returns a collection of menu items. Each menu item has an array of `children`. This is what actually your debug info shows.

So you should do smth like that:

```
@foreach (\Backpack\MenuCRUD\app\Models\MenuItem::getTree() as $parent)

    @foreach ($parent->children as $child)

    @endforeach     

@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, this makes sense and fixed my issues. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is code compatible with the standard backpack base theme.

Note that clicking on a parent item toggles the child visibility. If the parent has a url, it will not be linked.

```
@foreach (\App\Models\MenuItem::getTree(); as $item)
    @if($item->children->count() == 0)
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{$item->url()}}">
                {{ $item->name }}
            </a>
        </li>
    @else
        <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                {{ $item->name }}
            </a>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
                @foreach($item->children as $child)
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ $child->url() }}">
                        <i class=""></i> {{ $child->name }}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```